# Add array item then re-evaluate new array

Tags: php, arrays

Have been scratching my head for a few hours on this, seems like a silly issue, but just can't find a solution.

Here's my sample code:

```
$continueLoop = true;
$colorsArray = array("red", "white", "blue");

while($continueLoop == true) {

$arrayCount = count($colorsArray);

for ($i=0; $i < $arrayCount; $i++) {
    echo "evaluating ".$colorsArray[$i]."<br>";
    if($colorsArray[$i] == "blue") {
        array_push($colorsArray, "YELLOW");
        break;
    }
}

if(count($colorsArray) == 4) {
    $continueLoop = false;
}

}
```

It outputs

> red
>
> white
>
> blue

Basically I am adding a color "YELLOW" and then it should walk through the whole array again. But it's ignoring the newly added array item.

I know it does recognize the item, because the while loop will keep running until $colorsArray has 4 items (in the beginning it has only 3).

So why is it not Echo'ing "YELLOW"?

I've tried a few different solutions, just pushing the item using $array[], using foreach, array_values etc. etc.

Thank you

**Update:**

If i put

> if(count($colorsArray) == 10) {

Still still won't print Yellow

Comment: You specifically prevent the additional iteration with your `$continueLoop = false;` command...

Comment: also break in if will not show yellow index

Comment: You break out of the `for` and then set `$continueLoop = false` so everything is done and it doesn't loop again to echo yellow.

Comment: but if I put if(count($colorsArray) == 10) it stil won't print Yellow. It will print 'red','white','blue' 8 times, but never Yellow. Is it because of the break statement? It's as if "break" will always take precedence over "echo"?

Comment: damn it, you're right.. It never reaches the new array items it adds because it breaks out of the loop when it reaches "blue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will probably clean this up in a moment but just quickly this should do the job;

```
$colorsArray = array("red", "white", "blue");

for ($i=0; $i < count($colorsArray); $i++) {
    echo "evaluating ".$colorsArray[$i]."<br>";
    if($colorsArray[$i] == "blue" && !in_array('YELLOW', $colorsArray)) {
        array_push($colorsArray, "YELLOW");
    }
}

print_r($colorsArray);
```

Essentially you use count on each iteration, since the length of the array changes, it now has another element to loop through.

**Edit:** If you want it to walk through the **whole** array again, just set `$i = -1;` after you push in a new element.

**Edit2:** A little clean up.

```
$colours = array('red', 'white', 'blue');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($colours); ++$i) {
    echo 'Evaluating: ' . $colours[$i] . '<br/>';

    if ($colours[$i] === 'blue' && !in_array('Yellow', $colours)) {
        array_push($colours, 'Yellow');
        $i = -1;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Evaluating: red
Evaluating: white
Evaluating: blue
Evaluating: red
Evaluating: white
Evaluating: blue
Evaluating: Yellow
```

- If you reset the loot to `0` rather than `-1` then you skip the first loop iteration, i.e. you miss out red.
- Not sure on your dataset / purpose for this but I imagine you would want 'Yellow' to be dynamic.

Comment: Hi Pigeon, appreciate the effort you put into this. The thing is that I need break statements in there. It's part of a much larger script. When I run your script it works, but it won't work with break statements inside.

Comment: nm it was a dumb question, of course it won't show yellow, because each time it breaks out of the loop when it reaches "blue".. even if i was to add 1000 yellow in there it would never show them.